# UITextView with long text - text is cut off at the end

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a problem with displaying long text in UITextView placed in UIScrollView. The text is shown cutted at end!

I tried to get the contentSize with font name and size with no hope.

Any idea?

Comment: You will have to share some code before anyone can help you...

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your text view? That will give us a better idea idea of how your text is being truncated. Does it show the "..." or does it just end? Also, a UITextView _is_ a UIScrollView, so you may not need to put the text view in a scroll view.

Comment: Thank you, Please check the screenshot http://s8.postimg.org/qgm5qltt1/image.jpg

Comment: So, you want to display your entire text, so that it scrolls when it is higher than screen height? You will probably have to dynamically set height of your textview.. Also as Steve said, textview is scrollview so if you want to display only text, you dont need to use scrollview as well..

Comment: This is a defect in iOS 7. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966675/uitextview-in-ios7-clips-the-last-line-of-text-string/