# iOS 7 UITextView Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview

I have noticed in iOS 7 the last line of a `UITextView` after reaching the bottom is always hidden. This even happens in the Calendar app when you add a note to an event.

I have tried setting contentInsets and textContainerInset, none of them have made any difference.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and if so is there a workaround?

[image: Calendar UITextView Bug]

Comment: me too experiencing the same issue but not getting any solution for it...

Comment: Have you filed a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com ?

Comment: @Abizem I tried filing a bug report, but there was an error with the bug reporter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextView in iOS7 clips the last line of text string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966675/uitextview-in-ios7-clips-the-last-line-of-text-string)

Comment: You can get the answer from the below Stackoverflow link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966675/uitextview-in-ios7-clips-the-last-line-of-text-string

Answer (score 2):

I am having alternate solution to overcome the problem:

1. Implement `TextViewDelegate` in your `ViewController`.
2. Set delegate to `self` for your `textView`.
3. Implement `textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:`.

Example:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];

    return YES;
}
```

Now, run your code, By doing this, when you press '\n'(Enter) your curson will not be visible, but as you press the next character it will be going to make it visible.

Comment: There is also another solution over here, you can also use that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966675/uitextview-in-ios7-clips-the-last-line-of-text-string/19277383#19277383

Comment: Just your approach, the issue is the textView scrolls with the second character after \n and not the next one directly after \n. Any ideas?

Comment: Ya, i know that, it was the way i know, you can use the link that i provided in my previos comment, i dont have tried this but, i think so, that will work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this Library, that claims to fix the problem, it's better, but not quite fixing the problem

https://github.com/Exile90/ICTextView